# Eliminate if-else from while-loop

Tags: class, if-statement, design-patterns, while-loop

I have two class:

```
class A:
    b = B()
    function doSomething():
        while True:
             b.doSomething()

class B:
    counter = 0
    function doSomething():
        if counter < 10: 
            performMethod1()
        else:
            performMethod2()
        counter += 1
    function performMethod1(): ...
    function performMethod2(): ...
```

I feel this code is bad, because I know that B.performMethod2() is going to be performed much more times than B.performMethod1(), but the if-else (if counter < 10) is going to be checked every time I go inside B.doSomething().

Additionally, I don't want to break the while-loop of class A, because I want to hide the implementation details of class B from A.doSomething().

Is there any good way to eliminate the if-else of B.doSomething()? Thank you.

Comment: Check out this site http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for questions like that

Comment: @Querenker Code Review is for concrete, real implementations only! In this case, it would get closed as example code, as well as a lack of implementation.

Comment: @Pimgd Thanks for your explanation. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [state pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/state). 
Then you would create two states, one for cases where counter < 10 (stateA) and one were counter is >= 10 (statB). The transition from stateA, the initial stat, to stateB would happen when the counter in stateA reaches 10.

Answer (score 0):

The overhead for your if statement should be pretty minimal and not a problem.  But if you need to optimize it you could try something like this.

```
class A:
    b = B()
    function doSomething():

        while True:
             if b.counter < 10: 
                 b.doSomething1()
             else:
                 break

        while True:
             b.doSomething2()
class B:
    counter = 0

    function doSomething1():
        performMethod1()
        counter += 1

    function doSomething2():
        performMethod2()
        counter += 1

    function performMethod1(): ...
    function performMethod2(): ...
```